# Deleting comments

Tags: javascript, mysql

I was storing the comments in mysql with comment id for each of them (auto increment) and  when i retrive them  and show to the users i store each comments comment_id in an hidden input..so when the user wants to delete the comment i need to have the id of the comment what if some body just changes the value through javascript edit.? and sends it to server ..other comments might be deleted right...becoz the commnet_id being auto incremented values they are like...1,2.3....i suppose..how its done usually..?

Comment: Abhilash: Its rare case that user would realise all your logic :). but still to have a better code, store the comment_id in a session variable. this way it will be out of reach from user

Comment: on a second note, its not a good practice to store values in hidden variables ,its tedious as well as confusing

Comment: Your question lacks enough data to be answered properly, but in the end it all boils down to user permissions. My answer assumes a login system involved as it is one of the easiest form of setting up user permissions.

Comment: @dreamweiver What would you recommend then? I personally use `data-*` attributes when associating IDs to certain items, but hidden inputs are really useful when you have a value has to be sent along with other form data through `$('form').serialize()`.

Comment: Fabricio :In this scenario,there would too many hidden fields depending on the comments modified by user, so i personally recommend using session variable, if its a php script, then $_SESSION['comment_id'] =.... can be used. this avoids 1.not required to create too many input fields which is tedious. 2.submitting the form with too many hidden fields often leads to many problems at server side for processing.

Answer (score 2):

You simply validate whether the logged in user has the permission to delete the given comment in the back-end. If you gave the user permission to do it, it doesn't matter how he sent the request to do it.

For example, if users are allowed to only delete their own comments, check if the commenter_id is the same as the logged in user's id before executing the `DELETE` query.

Comment: Hmm that was the solution thanks Fabricio...however i was thinking in terms of obfuscating things on the client side...thnakyou again

Comment: @abilash No problem. `=]` side-note: All obfuscation can be easily bypassed as at some point the code will have to be decoded, also one can easily watch over the Network console tab to see all outgoing requests and redo/edit those so client-side obfuscation isn't of much help. See [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to control access permissions.

Usually only the authors or admins\moderators can delete.

Also you can just 
update comments set is_deleted=1 where comment_id='$comment_id'

Useful if site moderators are not site admins. And site admins can control moderators

Comment: sheldes hmm what if user has to delete his own comments.? this has nothing to do  with admins/moderators

Comment: but it can help moderators to find out the "flamestarter" (it is my real life situation: I have to administrate one forum. hiding instead of deleting helps alot)